# Как проверить видимость элемента на странице с помощью jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery позволяет изменять видимость элементов с помощью таких функций как `.hide()`, `.show()` или `.toggle()`.

Как проверить, видим элемент или нет, с помощью jQuery?

*(вопрос переведён с английского; ссылка на оригинал: [Testing if something is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden))*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

У jQuery есть псевдо-селекторы [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) и [`:hidden`](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/). Следовательно:

```
if ($element.is(':visible')) {
    // $element виден
}

if ($element.is(':hidden')) {
    // $element не виден
}
```

Однако, нужно учитывать, что в большинстве случаев данные селекторы проверяют наличие или отсутствие CSS стиля `display: none`. Элементы со стилями `visibility: hidden` или `opacity: 0` все равно будут считаться видимыми, поскольку визуально занимают место в теле документа.

Comment: Ответ не работает если проверяются все элементы, в т.ч. и во вкладках. Например у нас есть 7 таблиц, раскиданных по "nav-tabs", и проверить нужно все строки, то методом $element.is(':visible') выберутся только те, которые видны на открытой вкладке. Лучше проверять через атрибуты: $(element).css('display') === 'none'

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($(elem).is(':hidden')) {
   ...
}
```